# Mimic a slow internet connection (mac)

Tags: performance, macos, broadband

Anyone have a good technique for checking sites over a slower connection on osx?

Looking at posts on here, some people have recommended sloppy, which doesn't appear to do anything, just loads sites at normal speed. Any other techniques out there? I have 50mb broadband and it's difficult to judge page speeds at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Video demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgwR230coOw) of [Dummynet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/) used to throttle IP video streaming on OSX. According to the [website](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/), it is already installed in a standard OSX. As [Jeff Foster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128645/jeff-foster) mentioned, [the same question](https://superuser.com/questions/126642/throttle-network-bandwidth-per-application-in-mac-os-x) is on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). There I also found [ThrottledCLI](http://intrarts.com/throttledcli.html) suggested by [Robbie](https://superuser.com/users/44196/robbie).

Answer (score 1):

This might help you to simulate 3G on Mac:

```
sudo ipfw add pipe 1 src-port http
ipfw pipe 1 config delay 200 bw 700kbit/s
```

Remove those settings and go back to normal speeds:

```
ipfw flush
```

Also check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ipfw.8.html) out.